# Incremental over-approximation of DAG reachability

Tags: reference-request, graphs, approximation

I'm looking for a data structure that stores an approximation of a DAG:

1. If a node $x$ is reachable from a node $y$ in the DAG, then it is reachable in the approximation.
2. For a given fairly small root set of nodes that have no incoming edges, it supports getting an over-approximation of nodes reachable from a root and removing those returned nodes.
3. It supports insertion of roots and of non-roots.

Although I'm more concerned with practical performance (and space usage) than theoretical complexity, I'm just trying to figure out what to search for

Comment: If you're more concerned with practical performance, then I'm not sure this is the best site for you.

Comment: Also, what does it mean to "get nodes reachable from a root"?  Does this mean, given a root, return a list of all nodes reachable from that root?  Return a list that includes all nodes reachable from that root and possibly others?  What does it mean to "remove nodes reachable from a root"?  Does it mean, given a node, remove that node -- but the operation is only allowed to be performed if the node is actually reachable from some root?  What happens if I try to remove some node that isn't of this form?  Please edit to specify the desired semantics more clearly.